# javascript div closing problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that opens when user clicks link. And the div sort hovers over the link (its a more info box/div) and the div has a links and text. Now what I want is that when user cliks outside of the div it closes/disappears. But I want the links inside of div to work. Atm the javascript for that closin is like this:

```
$('html').click( function() {
   $('#moreInfo').hide();                                           
});
```

But the problem is that when user clicks the link inside of that #moreInfo the link doesn't work and the div just closes (it should go to different page from that link, not close the div).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$(document).click(function() {
  $('#moreInfo').hide();                                           
});
$('#moreInfo').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

By using [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on the `click` handler for the `<div>`, clicks coming from *inside* won't [bubble up](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) to where you have a handler to close it...which is what's currently happening.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you don't want to hide the DIV, you want to remove it from the DOM tree.

If this is the case, try this:

```
$('#moreInfo').remove();
```

Just remember to keep the reference to the item, so that you can re-add it when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to put a closing X on the up right corner of your DIV (like a window)... In other case, you can handle blur event of a "special" element inside your div.

Hope that helps,